# Как скачать изображения через rest api в папку

Tags: python, rest

Таким запросом скачиваю изображение

```
os.mkdir(path+"files")
response = requests.get(".../rest/files/photos/1?token=" + str(to_python["token"]))
```

в response я так понимаю находится файл в двоичном формате. Как в созданную папку скачать или переместить файл?

Comment: Что тот сервер в ответ возвращает? Сам файл? Или какой-нибудь json с ссылкой на файл? Если первое, то файл будет доступен из `.content`

Comment: json файл, который оповещает о пустом теле запроса

Comment: Так в ответе `находится файл в двоичном формате` или `json`, `который оповещает о пустом теле запроса`? Во втором случае, это как я понимаю означает проблему составления запроса

Comment: Я так понял от реализации api зависит это, я думал имеется стандарт, по дефолту так сказать. Да проблема в запросе была. Получилось передать файл, сейчас он находится в response, а как его в файл превратить?

Comment: `open('file.jpg', 'wb').write(response.content)`?

Comment: Да, то что нужно! Спасибо большое! Как ответ оформите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в ответе на запрос приходит файл, тогда скачать его можно так:

```
open('file.jpg', 'wb').write(response.content)
```

А лучше так:

```
with open('file.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Возник вопрос, а если два файла в ответе, как их сохранить?

Comment: @helldrg, сложно представить такое без всякого разврата типа 1) отправка одним куском но с разделителем 2) архивом 3) xml/json/... с закодированием типа в Hex/Base64. Без примера ответа с несколькими файлами помочь смогу только поддержкой, мол вы справитесь, верьте в себя :)

Comment: =) тоесть если те, кто писали апишку реализовали такую возможнось, разделив, например изображения каким либо разделителем то можно. Спасибо большое!